# Get MainMenu of other Running Application other then the Main Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4

I know the question is kinda confusing, but let me explain...

I want to be able to get the Menu Item Titles of all running applications, not just the main application.  I know how to get the main application menu items by using the code below:

```
NSMenu *mainMenu = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainMenu];

for (NSMenuItem *item in [mainMenu itemArray]){
    NSLog(@"%@", [item title]);
}
```

And I also know how to get a list of all running applications using the code below:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]
```

Now I want to be able to be able to get the mainMenu of a certain application in the sharedWorkspace.

Is this possible..  If so, please share :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Accessibility API to get access to other application's GUI elements. Keep in mind that you (or your app's customers) will need to turn on the "*Enable access for assistive devices*" in the *Universal Access* system preference.

To get started see [The Accessibility Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXOverview/cocoaAXOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001057-BBCJHHGJ).

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for code, but this got me on the right track. Now I sorta have an idea of how to make it work! Really appreciate the quick answer!

Comment: Sample code is worth a thousand pages of documentation: <https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html>